# Knockout JS issue with tinymce textarea

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, tinymce, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

#### Javascript

```
var tiny_options = {
    height: 120,
    width: 300,
    mode: 'textareas',
    theme: 'advanced',
    theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bold,italic,underline',
    theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
    theme_advanced_fonts: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif,Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace,Georgia=georgia,times new roman,times,serif,Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif,Times=times new roman,times,serif,Verdana=verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: 'top',
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: 'left'
};


//tinymce.init(tiny_options); // Please, remove comment to activate the tinymce

var initData = function (d) {
    this.id = ko.observable(d.id);
    this.text = ko.observable(d.text);
};

var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this,
        data = [{
            id: 1,
            text: 'some text 1'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            text: 'some text 2'
        }];

    self.dataSet = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.each(data, function (i, d) {
        self.dataSet.push(new initData(d));
    });
};

var model = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

#### UI

```
<!-- ko foreach : dataSet -->
<br>
<textarea data-bind="value: text, valueUpdate : 'change'"></textarea>
<br>
<!-- /ko -->
```

### **[*Link to Demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/yJ5GV/171/)**

---

Above, code is working fine, i.e. model data is updating nicely without `tinymce` binding, but when I activate the `tinymce`, view model observable is not updating. I tried **[*this*](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---tinyMCE)** also, but no result.

So, Please help me to configure, how can I update the view model observables using `tinymce` binding?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that will bind up the value and apply the TinyMCE Editor to your `<textarea>`.  The net result looking something like this;

```
<textarea data-bind="wysiwyg: text"></textarea>
```

Give the one I've put together on Github a try https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple custom binding to update observable:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.richTextEditor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        window.tinymce.init({
            target: element,
            skin: "lightgray",
            menubar: false,
            statusbar: false,
            forced_root_block: false,
            browser_spellcheck: true,
            toolbar: "bold italic underline",
            valid_elements: "strong,br,em,span[style|class|id|data],i[class]",
            formats: {
                bold: { inline: "strong" },
                italic: { inline: "em" },
                underline: { inline: "span", styles: { "text-decoration": "underline" } }
            },
            plugins: "paste",
            resize: false,
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on("change", function () {
                    var textInputBinding = allBindings().textInput;
                    var content = this.getContent();
                    textInputBinding && textInputBinding(content);
               });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

the binding on `textarea` should be `data-bind="textInput: yourObservable"`.